# How neutral culture is mapped to a specific culture in CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture method?

Tags: c#, .net, localization, cultureinfo

I don't know how Neutral Culture is mapped to a Specific Culture. Is it static like below?

```
en = en-US    
fr = fr-FR    
pt = pt-BR
```

I checked 
http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/cultureinfo.cs,44db57d9e190258e,references

&
nativeInitCultureData from https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/classlibnative/nls/nlsinfo.cpp

but I couldn't understand. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 8):

I don't think there is an *exact* mapping here.

`en` and `en-US` cultures are different based on their [`LCID` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.lcid) which has `0x0009` and `0x0409` in order. The `en` is a neural culture that is associated with a language but **not** with a country or region.

But `en-US` is a specific culture which associated with **both** a language and a country or region.

That's why you can create a [`RegionInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.regioninfo) with `en-US`

```
var region = new RegionInfo("en-US");
```

but you *can't* create with `en`

```
var region = new RegionInfo("en");
```

which says;

> The region name `en` should **not** correspond to neutral culture; a
>   specific culture name is required.

There is an hierarchy between `CultureInfo` objects which the [`Parent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.parent) of a specific culture is a neutral culture and the parent of a neutral culture is the [`InvariantCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture).

Let me visualize it for you how this hierarchy works for `en` neutral culture:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

**Almost**, there is a parent relationship between cultures. You can see this via:

```
var specificCultures = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultures(System.Globalization.CultureTypes.SpecificCultures);
foreach (var culture in specificCultures)
{
     var text = "Specific: " + culture.Name + " Parent: " + culture.Parent.Name;
     Console.WriteLine(text);
}
```

Giving (extract of output):

> Specific: ar-SA Parent: ar
>   Specific: bg-BG Parent: bg
>   Specific: ca-ES Parent: ca
>   Specific: zh-TW Parent: zh-CHT
>   Specific: cs-CZ Parent: cs
>   Specific: da-DK Parent: da
>   Specific: de-DE Parent: de
>   Specific: el-GR Parent: el
>   Specific: en-US Parent: en
>   Specific: fi-FI Parent: fi
>   Specific: fr-FR Parent: fr
>   Specific: he-IL Parent: he

You can see from this snippet that the parent of `zh-TW` is `zh-CHT`. But that does get down to `zh` eventually (via `zh-Hant`). Following a parent of a specific culture will get you down to a neutral one eventually.