# .NET 6 Blazor Problem getting regions from all countries

Tags: c#, blazor, .net-6.0

I have a Blazor project. This code was working perfect in .NET 5, after I upgraded to .NET 6 I started getting problems.

The code `CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures)` is retunrning noisy stuff.

```cs
private static List<CountryInfo> GetAllCountries(CultureTypes cultureTypes)
{
    List<CountryInfo> Countries = new List<CountryInfo>();

    foreach (CultureInfo culture in CultureInfo.GetCultures(cultureTypes))
    {
        if (culture.LCID != 127)
            Countries.Add(new CountryInfo()
            {
                Culture = culture,
                Region = new RegionInfo(culture.TextInfo.CultureName)
            });
    }
    return Countries;
}
```

It gives an exception after a few cultures.

> The region name en should not correspond to neutral culture; a specific culture name is required.

The line where it breaks is:

```cs
Region = new RegionInfo(culture.TextInfo.CultureName)
```

This is the value of the culture that is crashing:

[image]

Any clue?

Comment: Which line throws the exception?

Comment: @canton7 I just updated the post with more info. Thanks

Comment: So your whole question can be reduced to `new RegionInfo("en")`?

Comment: Instead of passing `cultureTypes` you could ask just for `SpecificCultures`

Comment: Just skip cultures where `IsNeutralCulture` is `true`?

Comment: What value of `CultureTypes` are you using?

Comment: I don't think `new RegionInfo("en")` ever worked, even on .NET Framework. [See here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZQ1jgM). It makes no sense either, `en` isn't a region. That's why I'm interested in the value of `cultureTypes`, since anything other than `SpecificCultures` is either deprecated, or doesn't make sense to use with `RegionInfo` like that

Comment: Does this answer your question: [How neutral culture is mapped to a specific culture in CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture method?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35152134/880990)

Comment: @canton7 Im using CultureTypes.SpecificCultures

Comment: Using `CultureTypes.SpecificCultures` does not give me an error

Comment: Are you sure? [I don't see 'en' in the resulting list](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgNAFxAJwK4wD4AEBMAGAWAChcBGYrPAAi1IDoBxAGwHtgImoAvCBKFmAG5ixAGYtkAUwgBjABZUAFADcIyKgA8qsKgGFUTBKikBJGOMaSE+w8ckBnRTaNSAKgE8ADg7oBlbzJQolAyznb2AJQRxADexFQJCbQAnIoadAByEGCSEYKJxAC+xEA)

Comment: That't very strange. Let me create a new .NET 6 console app and copy same code.

Comment: Woow in .NET 6 console doesn't break. I'm doing this on Blazor actually.

Comment: So, the problem is actually that in .NET 6 with Blazor, `CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures)` returns neutral cultures as well? Maybe worth re-phrasing the question to make this clear? As a workaround you can filter them out yourself, as suggested by @MartinCostello

Comment: Yes let me rephrase the title of the post

Comment: And the body: there's info in the comments which is needed, and in fact the whole thing boilds down to the fact that `CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures)` returns the `en` culture -- everything else is noise